# StarUML Install Extension failed

Tags: staruml

I'm using StarUML to install java extension.

I have done following steps:

1. Tools -> Extension Manager..
2. Click Registry, Search java, then click Install button. [Extension Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X4a3.png)
3. Then error happens, saying: *Installation Failed. Unknown internal error.*
   [image]

I don't known how to solve it. I search this problem on google, but find nothing useful. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem.
StarUML version: 2.8.0
I installed successfully by manual.follow this:

```
1. Get an extension as a .zip file.
2. Extract the file on the extensions path.
/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/StarUML/extensions/user for Mac OS.
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\StarUML\extensions\user for Windows.
3. Check a folder in the extensions path and main.js file in the folder.
4. Restart StarUML.
```

More detail see the official document [Managing Extensions](http://docs.staruml.io/en/latest/managing-extensions.html)

Comment: Cool, steps worked for me. Thanks and +1. for completeness link to extensions: http://staruml.io/extensions

Comment: I had the same issue for 2.8.1. This workaround worked for me. Thanks

Comment: For Linux the extensions path can be found at `~/.config/StarUML/extensions/user`